# Why can't this be marshalled?

Tags: java, marshalling

This is a question that I've been asked in a Job Interview test:

What's wrong with the following class definition and why can't it be marshalled?

```
 public class SomeClass {

    private String s;

    public SomeClass(String someString) {
    this.s = someString;
    }
 }
```

I'm just starting my career and I don't think there's anything wrong with this class declaration, what am I missing?
And why can't it be marshalled? Because of the missing no-arg constructor?

Comment: Marshalled as what? With what?

Comment: that's all they said in the test

Comment: Terrible interview question.  No context provided.

Comment: it really depends on the way of marshalling. could be the missing no-arg constructor or the missing Serializable implementation. With few information like this, this question cannot be answered

Comment: Yeah, give everyone the name of the company to let others avoid it ;)

Comment: Probably means Serializable interface. It's a crappy question in my mind. But I suspect you were also expected to ask question about context too.